# Preload function not loaded in Nav component

Tags: svelte, sapper

It seems my `preload` function does not run (my `pages` variable is not fed as props of the Nav component).
In `_layout.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import Nav from "../components/Nav.svelte";
</script>
<Nav />
<main>
    <slot />
</main>
```

In `Nav.svelte`:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page) {
        const res = await this.fetch(
            "http://localhost:2368/ghost/api/v3/content/settings/?key=xxx"
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        return {
            pages: data.settings.navigation,
        };
    }
</script>
<script>
    export let pages;
    import { stores } from "@sapper/app";
    const { page } = stores();
</script>

<nav>
    <ul>
        {#each pages as p}
            <li>
                <a
                    class={p.url.includes(page.path) ? 'selected' : ''}
                    href={p.url}>{p.label}</a>
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The each loop rises `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
The wierd part is that if I do the preload in `_layout.svelte` and explicitely pass the return value as a props with `<Nav {pages} />` then the code works...
Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

This is expected. Preload functions only run in *page* and *layout* components, not the components that they import.

Comment: Is this something that is impossible or simply a design decision? I ran into a use case where this would have been very useful (pre-rendering a low resolution image that can be displayed as a blurred placeholder before the real image loads). What I am doing now is pre-rendering these placeholder images in the page component and then passing it as a prop to the component which is quite messy.